# What does localhost mean within a Windows terminal services server? Machine or session?

Tags: localhost, terminal-services

I'm investigating a project at the moment to create an application which will listen to "localhost" within a Windows terminal services environment.

I don't have access to a test environment at present, but I wanted to check this design, especially what localhost/loopback 127.0.0.1 means within a multiuser machine.

If my application binds a TCP socket listening on 127.0.0.1:40000 then what clients would be able to access this?
- would it be open to clients within all sessions for all users on the machine/server?
- or would it just be each individual user/session?

I'm hoping/guessing the latter. If this is the case, then can each user in each session open their own app running a listener on 127.0.0.1:40000?

Thanks for any help on this design issue.

Comment: To whoever voted to close: this is a question about whether I can develop a program which uses localhost in terminal services. IMHO it's definitely a software development question and so is in line with the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will disappoint you, it's the former.

TCP/IP sockets have no concept of "users" or "ownership": There are 65535 available ports on a given network interface, and there can only be one process listening at any given one. What user owns the process is irrelevant - if you have User1's process listening on 127.0.0.1:40000, then User2's process' attempt to listen on the same port will fail.

Likewise, there is no intrinsic access control: if there's a listening port at a given port, anything that can reach the computer at that port can access the port (in other words, the listening and connecting processes - server and client - don't need to belong to the same user; they might even be on different hosts).

Comment: Thanks Piskvor - that does make sense. I guess I just don't know what terminal services is... I kind of hoped every user got a separate VM - each VM with its own localhost adaptor, but I guess I need to understand sessions are different to VMs. Thanks!

Comment: @Stuart: You're welcome. As for TS, normally they're all executing on the same computer, without any virtualization. Each user only gets their own virtual *display*, but that's pretty much all - the rest of the computer (networking, processes etc) are shared.

Comment: Thanks again - I'm learning:) Does that mean they also share all folders like "program files" - they just get their own "My Documents"? (Sorry - should really ask these as separate questions - or should just go read up!)

Comment: @Stuart: Actually, yes, that'd be better as a separate question (on ServerFault perhaps?)